# Internet Explorer "setAttribute" onclick workaround?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onclick, setattribute

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.setAttribute("onclick",p.onrowclick+"("+row.id+")");
```

Hi, the above works fine for me in Firefox. I can't find the correct syntax for a workaround in IE.

I'm using IE8.

Comment: Did you consider using a JavaScript library?

Comment: The above code is what I used with a jQuery extension called Flexigrid so that I could add an onclick event to the tr. I just threw that code in without regard to jQuery or an 'easier approach'. I thought that if it wasn't working with the above code I'd have the same problem with any other way of assigning an onclick to a tr in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set events like this. Pass it a proper function:

```
tr.onclick = function() { p.onrowclick(...); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on IE only, but not the suggested way:

```
var tr = document.createElement('<tr onclick="p.onrowclick('+row.id+')">');
```